# find item inside list of list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of customers having another list within customers called series. My series can be `null` or contain data.
How can I find any item matching series value. I have tried the two mehods below  but with no success.

```
results = customers.Where(d => d.Series.Any(s => s.Contains("item")));

results = customers.Where(d => d.Series.Count() != 0).Where(s => s.Series.Contains("item"));
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is not working? If `customers.Series` is null, you may get a null reference exception ... is that the problem? On a side note, using `d.Series.Count()` is inefficient in the context in which you are using it because it will iterate through ALL Series items to determine if there are Zero. For your purpose, use `d.Series.Any()` That will only check for the existence of one - saving you many loop operations.

Comment: I too, would like to hear what the exact problem is. As you can see, the answers you're getting are (aside from a null-check, and both answers don't use .Contains within the "Any".) the same as the first line in your posted code.

Comment: should the null sets be included in the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go with:

```
results = customers.Where(d => d.Series!= null && d.Series.Any(s => s.Contains("item")));
```

in case you want an element in `Series` to actually contain the string `"item"` or

```
results = customers.Where(d => d.Series!= null && d.Series.Any(s => s.Equals("item")));
```

in case you want an element in `Series` to be a perfect match to `item`.

Comment: Incase your list "Series" contains word like "itemized" it will still give you a match when you check for "item" ie. it will do partial match due to the code `s.Contains("item")`.

Comment: @AmeyKamat I know and this may be the behavior the OP wants since this is in his approach too as: `s.Series.Contains("item")` and `s.Contains("item")`. In case it is not what one wants, can simple use `Equals` or `==` operator. It is still good pointing this out. Thanks!

Comment: `cust.Series.Contains("item")` and `cust.Series.Any(s => s.Contains("item"))` are two different things. `cust.Series.Contains("item")` will check if "item" is contained in the list (full match) and `cust.Series.Any(s => s.Contains("item"))` will check if "item" is contained in each string in the Series list. just FYI

Comment: @AmeyKamat you are perfectly right, the difference between collection and string catched my this time. It should be one good approach for this, I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you expect,

```
//For case sensitive
var results = customers.Where(d => d.Series != null && d.Series.Contains("item")));
```

OR

```
//For case insensitive
var results = customer.Where(d => d.Series != null && d.Series.Any(x => x.Equals("item", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
results = customers.Where(d => d.Series != null && d.Series.Any(s => s == "item"));
```

This will return all customers where their Series collection contains the value "item".

Comment: this will throw an exception if `d.Series` is null

Comment: @MatthewWhited Answer improved.